# ¿Qué le pasó a PluggablePanelMorph de Pharo 1.x a Pharo 5.x?

Tags: pharo, smalltalk

Estoy intentando seguir un tutorial de [PharoCast de UI](http://www.pharocasts.com/2010/01/basic-ui-building.html) en Pharo y me encontré con la sorpresa de que la clase `PluggablePanelMorph` ya no existe en Pharo 5.x.

```
aPanel := PluggablePanelMorph new.
```

[image: Busqueda en Finder de clases con el nombre PluggablePanel]

¿Fue deprecado o fue renombrado? ¿Qué puedo usar en vez de `PluggablePanelMorph` para continuar con el tutorial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Efectivamente, la clase fue [eliminada en Pharo 4](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-core/commit/4bc2e0b91ee3a0c12c74fde761c55d27d46a962a).

Según ese mismo commit, deberías poder [usar `PanelMorph` en su lugar](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-core/commit/4bc2e0b91ee3a0c12c74fde761c55d27d46a962a#diff-08cac124a415bfd41c6af2b375c8fd7b).